# How to Create a Patch in WiX with the product code as * in wxs

Tags: wix, installation, patch

I have an existing large WiX install that has already been released with the product code mentioned as *. I need to create a small install for just a couple of files that have changed. As the product code is mentioned as *, WiX doesn't allow creating an `msp` file as the product code differs. What can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Purely WiX approach to making patches](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_patching.htm), you can author a [Validate](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_validate.htm) element with attribute `ProductId='no'`. Like this:

```
<Media Id="..." Cabinet="my.cab">
  <PatchBaseline Id="...">
    <Validate ProductId="no" />
  </PatchBaseline>
</Media>
```

You might want to explore other options of the `Validate` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use major upgrades to create minor upgrade patches. You need to change Product/@Id to match the product code of your target product before building the newer version.